# Confusion on proof of $\lim_{x\to0} q(\frac1x) e^{-1/x^2} = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

I was looking over a proof in my textbook and it says that to prove $$\lim_{x\to 0} q\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) e^{-1/x^2} = 0$$ where $q$ is a polynomial defined as $$q(t) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} t^k$$
we only need to prove that for every natural n, $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^n} = 0$$
and it goes on to show that this inequality holds $\displaystyle 0\le \left|\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^n}\right|\le n!|x^n|$ if $x$ is not $0$ therefore it implies $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to0} q\left(\frac1x\right) e^{-1/x^2} = 0$. I don't understand how it reaches that conclusion from $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^n} = 0$ and the textbook does not give further explanation.

Comment: How is defined this function q?

Comment: @PAM1499 just a guess but $q(x)$ probably means a polynomial. OP however should add this detail

Comment: @NinadMunshi Oh I see. It probably is a polynomial

Comment: If I am misreading $q(\frac{1}{x})$, please let me know. It is ambiguous whether you mean $q$ as a function of $(\frac{1}{x})$ or $q\cdot\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: @CSquared q(x) is a standard notation for a polynomial, and given what OP's textbook said it seems likely this is the interpretation (however OP should still clarify since there is a chance this is not the case). We can say with certainty, however, that $$q\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\neq q \cdot \frac{1}{x}$$ is definitely not the meaning. It's definitely not that ambiguous that OP means a function of some kind.

Comment: sorry for the confusion q is a polynomial defined by the sum of t^k.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}q(1/x)e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}=\lim_{x \to 0}\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{x^k}e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}=\sum_{k=0}^n \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^k}e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}
$$
Since you know
$$
\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^k}e^{\frac{-1}{x^2}}=0
$$
for all $k$ natural the result follows.